# Define groups of functions

Tags: r, function, package

I'm working on building an R package, and I've encountered a structural problem that I'm not sure how I should solve.  I have several different distributions that I'd like to implement in my package (normal, student's t, etc.) and for each distribution I'll have several functions related to it.  I will then have an additional function that uses these functions to execute some process, and so I'm trying to avoid having to define all of these functions with different names.

To be more clear, let me give a simple example.  Let's say I want to write a simple package to do maximum likelihood estimation for several distributions.  Ideally, I'd like to call an `MLE` function like:

```
MLE(data, distribution = "normal")
```

and then have the MLE function load all the related normal distribution functions that it needs.  So, it may load `density` and `gradDensity` specific to the normal distribution and operate with these functions.  However, if I call

```
MLE(data, distribution = "studentT")
```

then `density` and `gradDensity` are defined as different functions, now specific to the Student's t distribution.

My question is this: how can I appropriately define the `density` and `gradDensity` functions for each different distribution I'm interested in and load them when I need them?  I've considered defining a new class for this package and having this object contain all the distribution functions I'd need, but this seems problematic because I want one of the functions in this object to be able to call another one of the functions in the object (for example, `gradDensity` may call `density`).  I also considered defining separate environments for each distribution, but I wasn't sure if that was good practice.  Ideally, I'd also like users to be able to define their own distribution and then use this package as well, but I'm having a hard time understanding how to appropriately construct this structure in R.

Comment: Would this toy example: `f <- list(min=min,max=max); f[['min']](1:5); f[['max']](1:5)` be of help for you?

Comment: Yeah, that's approaching what I'm looking for.  So, in my package, I'd like to define many such lists and many different min/max functions.  What's a good way to structure such code?

Comment: Interesting idea, @jenesaisquoi.  However, with this problem, I may also have functions that don't necessarily take a student object (for example, a function that converts a list of the parameters of the student's t into a numeric vector for optimization).  I would need those kinds of functions for each class, but I couldn't use this method to dispatch unless I passed the class into each of these functions, right?  And thanks for your help :)